# WCF service with impersonate cannot connect to SQL Server, but SSMS on the same machine will

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, sql-server, wcf

I have an issue that I simply cannot wrap my head around how to solve. In the bottom there's a WCF service (.NET 4.0) which is configured to impersonate a valid user like this:

```
<system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0" />
    <identity impersonate="true" password="abc123" userName="domain\theuser" />
</system.web>
```

And a SQL Server connection string that looks like this:

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="MyTest.Service.Properties.Settings.ConnStr"
         connectionString="Data Source=192.168.0.54;Initial Catalog=TheDatabase;Integrated Security=SSPI;" />
</connectionStrings>
```

I have the WCF service running under IIS7 and in an application pool that is also running with the same users credentials.

IF I try to access the database, WITH these credentials (the user is set up as a valid user on the SQL Server), in SSMS on the SAME machine, everything works fine, but as soon as I try the same thing with the WCF service it throws me this:

> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: Named Pipes Provider, error: 40 - Could not open a connection to SQL Server)

What on earth can be the issue? I have other applications running on the server accessing other external SQL Server databases without any troubles.

Comment: I believe you are just impersonating improperly. Why don't you just set the app pool identity to this specific user if all your requests should execute under that specific user?

Comment: I've removed the impersonation from the WCF application now (the application pool is still running with the users credentials). Still the same though.

Answer (score 0):

It's likely your connection string as it's not an error being given for credentials.

If the SQL server is local, you can try "datasource=(local)" instead.

You can also try adding in the instance to the datasource as well.

If it's a SQL server that is remote, make sure the SQL server is configured to allow remote connections

Comment: I used 10.0.0.1 just as an example. The real IP-address goes to a real SQL Server, however I'm not really into divulging that IP-address. :)

Comment: Gotcha, in that case, make sure you are providing the server name the exact same way you are when you successfully connect to it in SSMS. Also I'm making the assumption when you say you can connect to it on the same machine, you are referring to the same machine that is hosting the WCF service correct?

Comment: Yes, My server has SSMS installed, it works there, but not in the WCF. And the address is EXACTLY the same in both SSMS and the web.config.

Comment: The SQL server is remote. Tried with the Instance name but same issue.

Answer (score 0):

Taken from msdn

> If your database is on a remote server, you must also configure the
>   relevant accounts in Active Directory for delegation. For example, you
>   must ensure that your application's service account is marked as
>   Trusted for delegation and that end user accounts are not marked as
>   sensitive, which means that they cannot be delegated.